# OpenAM 11: Display exception from authenticating datastore

Tags: openam

We are using a custom database data store in OpenAM. This store authenticates user against our Oracle database.
Now, there are many possible causes why that authentication might fail. The account could be locked in Oracle or the password might be expired.
The datastore catches the SQLException, but how do I propagate the cause to the OpenAM UI?

I can throw a AuthLoginException from authenticate(), but on its way to the AMLoginContext, it gets wrapped and AMLoginContext kind of ignores error codes of AuthLoginExceptionS anyway. Meaning: AMLoginContext doesn't read the error code from the exception but tries to determine the error code itself, and usually it just puts AMAuthErrorCode.AUTH_LOGIN_FAILED into the login state.

How do I get the UI to show the cause of the login problem?

Comment: for security reasons the actual cause of the error is not shown, otherwise one would know that e.g. account exists, a wrong password was used, account is locked

Comment: Well, if the password of the user has expired, we kind of need to know that. How else would we prompt the user to change his password before he can proceed to the application!? If the account is locked, then there is also no point in making the user re-enter passwords.

Comment: You could extend the JDBC auth module and handle password expiration like it's done in the LDAP auth module .., the defalult data store auth module is not intended to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As Bernhard says, that is not recommended. However, from your data store you could obtain a Debug instance (com.sun.identity.shared.debug.Debug) and you can log exceptions, and they will appear in [AM_INSTALL_DIR]/openam/debug.

edit: You can find examples of doing so throughout the OpenAM source code.